# Android - Menu Bar below an element of a List

Tags: android, show-hide, menubar

I have a ListView. My point is, after selecting one of the elements on that view, I want to show a menubar Right below that element. What Im tryin to do is pretty much something like the app Any.Do.

Heres a [picture](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=pt-PT&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=9RPbcZMzBhS6RM:&imgrefurl=http://android.appstorm.net/reviews/productivity-reviews/any-do-helps-you-make-things-happen/&docid=lksoRGUDWLOCvM&imgurl=http://android.appstorm.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/AnyDO2.jpg&w=800&h=1280&ei=x56GT8TiF4SmhAf87cDRCA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=402&vpy=107&dur=617&hovh=284&hovw=177&tx=106&ty=174&sig=111827409133443286618&page=1&tbnh=139&tbnw=100&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:1,s:0,i:68) of what I intent to do.

How can I do it ? Id rather not use GreenDroid.

To fill the array I use this code snniped:

TaskBoard.class

```
setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, array_tasks, R.layout.dash_tasks,
  new String[] { "task", "project" , "date"}, new int[] { R.id.dashtask,
  R.id.taskproject, R.id.final_date}));
```

R.layout.dash_tasks is the view im showing to the user.
This is a code snipped to call the menubar I want to show:

dash_tasks.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/menu_bar"
            style="@style/page"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:visibility="gone">

            <include layout="@layout/menubar"></include>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

**EDITED:**

Ive figured out how can I find the position Im clicking. The problem is, its a relative position. I mean, if I click in the 2nd item on the array, the menubar will apear in the 2nd position every 7 items (thts the number of items that fill a page). Im guessin this position is acording to the screen and not the ListView..

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        View x= parent.getChildAt(position);
        View a= x.findViewById(R.id.mini_menu_bar);
        a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I hope this helps you understand the problem

Comment: look this : http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: you mean showing view out of phone edges? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link @nibha but i dont want to use QuickAction Dialogs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

What you do is that in your list items layout xml you also have the menu (wrapped in a vertical linearlayout) but set it to android:visibility="gone". When the item is pressed you just show that hidden menu view.

Comment: I have tried doing that but when I do that the menu bar appears below every element and not the one I selected..

Comment: well you're doing something wrong if it appears below all the items. in your adapter have a selectedItem variable and in getView do if(selectedItem == postion){}else{}. On list item press you set the selected item in adapter and refresh the data

Comment: With the code I presented above it does something really akward. Everytime I select an item from the list, the menubar apears once every 8 items. Imagine I have 30 Tasks, no matter what item I select, the menubar Will appear on the 1st, 9th, 17th and so on...

Comment: that is probably because you are using the convertview which is a recycled view, you have to explicitly hide the menu bar if it is not needed

Comment: Its not that...I think its because of the SimpleAdapter. I can only see 8 tasks in one page (to see more I have to scroll down), and thats where the 2nd menubar appears. I assume that the SimpleAdapter fills per page, so the menu bar appears the number of times the SimpleAdapter was called. The first thing I do is Hide the menubar (dash_task.xml)

Comment: Ah ok you are not using a custom adapter? You will have to implement a custom list adapter for this functionality

Comment: Custom Adapter? Do you know how can I fill the listview with simpleAdapter ? I mean, there has got to be a way to put all the array info into the layout instead of putting 7 at a time.

Comment: look inte subclassing BaseAdapter instead of using SimpleAdapter, there are lots of tutorials of this if you just google for "android custom list adapter"

Comment: @Waqas +1 THANK you! I was looking for the name of that thing (QuickAction), you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many view you wanna display at the same time. If there is only one, and you want it to sorta stand out without much of programming I would go for `QuickAction`. If you have multiple views at the same time expanded, my suggestion would be to use `RelativeLayout` and BeLow. What you need to do is fairly simple. Make sure there is a way for your to find the item below the tapped on, add the new view below the tapped item and add the change the item bellow tapped item to be below the new item. Something like the code below

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId());
```

Another solution would be to use `LinearLayout` but requires a loop to find the index of the item tapped on and adding the new item below it:

```
parent.addView(subItem, index+1);
```

Comment: It didnt work.. I ve tried using this code inside the listener but it didnt do anything...beside I already have the RelativeLayout created, I just want to set visibility VISIBLE below the item...

Comment: The code above is using `RelativeView` instead `ListView`. Plus, view Id should be set too.

Comment: The view ID is already given to you (In the Listener method) so thats what I was using.

Comment: If you could put your code here for me. It'd difficult for me to tell, without having a glance at it.